# How do I add more sub columns in an overall table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{tabular}{llr}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          &    each     & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I know that this code gives me 2 sub columns, one over animal and description, but there is no column header over 'Price', how could I edit this table to do that? I know the {1-2} makes it over the first 2 column names, but what if I want a new column header over Price (such as money?) Meaning I want 3 columns still, one header over the first 2 and another header over the last one.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that be somewhat redundant?

Comment: you have posted the example in a form that we can not use it but I think you want `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & some text here \\ `

Comment: You can stack `\cmidrule`s next to one another. For example, try `\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}` and add a heading `Money` in the previous line.

Comment: Hi Werner, where exactly would I add it in the previous line? I was testing things out and all I got was errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this example I got directly from wikipedia :(

Comment: @Wallace: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llr}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & your text here\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, @leandriis!! If you'd like I can give you best answer for this problem as this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Wallace i mean that it is helpul to post the example as in the answer, a document that shows the problem, your code block is missing \documentclass, \begin{doument} etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & Money \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} llr @{}}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          &    each     & 0.01       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{@{} llr @{}}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & Money \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          &    each     & 0.01       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm following your steps, @Mico and thank you for this suggestion, but I can't seem to now add an additional 4th column without receiving an error. Is it not as simple as adding an additional '&' in the midrule section? Like this:
```
\begin{tabular}{@{} llr @{}}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & Money \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
Animal    & Description & Price &Here(\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65 &Here   \\
          &    each     & 0.01  &Here too     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```
Assuming I don't want the new column to have a header

Comment: @Wallace - If you need to add an entire column -- say, a right-aligned column -- rather than just add a header to an existing column, be sure to change `\begin{tabular}{@{} llr @{}} ` to `\begin{tabular}{@{} llrr @{}} `. This will inform LaTeX to expect 4 rather than just 3 columns.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you so much, @Mico